# AutoMapper Map DTO Properties to Model List

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a DTO object like this:

```
public class Original {

     public string Item1 { get; set; }
     public string Item2 { get; set; }
     public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I want to use AutoMapper to map those 3 items to a `List<string>` property on my model.

```
public class Model {

     public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not even sure what to post as what I've already tried as it's just been nothing even close.

Comment: .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<string> { dest.Item1, dest.Item2, dest.Item3 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a simple map for that:

```
CreateMap<Original, Model>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<string> {dest.Item1, dest.Item2, dest.Item3});
```